# Stop a dynamic bound eventhandler to fire immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I'm using jQuery 2.1.3. I try to build a button that will show/hide content on click. I also want to hide the content when there's a click on a wrapping container (in my application it's the document itself, but I used a regular div in my example below). As there is some more logic to handle I'm also making use of custom events that I fire via `.trigger()`.

This works fine but I have a problem. When I show the hidden content I apply an eventlistener to document to hide the content when the user clicks anywhere on it. This eventhandler is fired straight after the content is shown resulting in my content gets hidden immediately.

I can only get around this by using `$evt.stopPropagation()` in my toggle buttons event handler. But that's no solution for me as I need the event to bubble up as other elements listen for that.

Heres the simplified HTML:

```
<div id="document">
    <button id="btn" type="button">Toggle</button>
    <div id="content" class="hidden">Hidden Content</div>
</div>
```

And heres the JS to this:

```
//trigger custom show event
var show = function () {
    $("#document").trigger("show");
};

//trigger custom hide event
var hide = function () {
    $("#document").trigger("hide");
};

//handle custom show event
$("#document").on("show", function () {
    $("#content").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#document").on("click", hide);//add listener to container, fires immediately
});

//handle custom hide event
$("#document").on("hide", function () {
    $("#document").off("click", hide);//remove listener from container
    $("#content").addClass("hidden");
});

//on toggle button click call custom events
$("#btn").click(function ($evt) {
    //$evt.stopPropagation(); would work but event should propagate
    $("#content").hasClass("hidden") ? show() : hide();
});
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7jws1cub/)**

**What could I do about this? Stopping event propagation on toggle button click would show my content but i need this event to bubble up as there are other elements around waiting for that. How could I avoid that the applied event listener on document fires immediately?**

PS: jQuerys `.show()/.hide()` functions are no alternative for me.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: what about `setTimeout(function () {$("#document").on("click", hide);}, 0)`?

see [here](https://github.com/ePages-de/scribe-plugin-enhanced-link-tooltip/blob/master/scribe-plugin-link-tooltip.js#L184]

Comment: @PaoloPriotto: Yes, that would work. But it looks like kind of a hack to me...is this a common solution?

Comment: I've removed the custom events but it shows the same behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/7jws1cub/2/ - So is using a timeout my only solution? Is this a safe one?

Comment: you could also check if `e.target` equals `btn` and in that case not hide the `content`